# Row size of a 2D undeclared array

Tags: c

**int array[][2] = {{1,2},{1,2}};**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[][2] = {{1,2},{1,2}};
    int total = sizeof(array);

    int column = sizeof(array[0]);
    int row = total / column;

    printf("Total fields: %d\n", total);
    printf("Number of rows: %d\n", row);
    printf("Number of columns: %d\n", column);

    return 0;
}
```

**Column number becomes a problem now.**

Comment: The number of columns is `sizeof array[0] / sizeof array[0][0]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the Posting Guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your question doesn't exactly explain what the problem is.  What are you getting? What are you expecting? Are there any errors? Does it crash? These are things that make a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Column number becomes a problem now.

There is no problem at all :)

Number of rows:

```
size_t nrows = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

or

```
size_t nrows = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
```

Number of columns:

```
size_t ncols = sizeof(array[0]) / sizeof(array[0][0]);
```

or

```
size_t ncols = sizeof(*array) / sizeof(**array);
```

example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[][2] = {{1,2},{1,2}};
    size_t total = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0][0]);
    size_t total1 = sizeof(array) / sizeof(**array);

    size_t columns = sizeof(array[0]) / sizeof(array[0][0]);
    size_t rows = sizeof(array) /sizeof(array[0]);
    size_t columns1 = sizeof(*array) / sizeof(**array);
    size_t rows1 = sizeof(array) /sizeof(*array);

    printf("Total elements: %zu\n", total);
    printf("Number of rows: %zu\n", rows);
    printf("Number of columns: %zu\n", columns);

    printf("Total elements: %zu\n", total1);
    printf("Number of rows: %zu\n", rows1);
    printf("Number of columns: %zu\n", columns1);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8YjG79Man

Some remarks:
Correct type for sizes is `size_t`

`int main()` -> `int main(void)`

Comment: int mat6[][3] = {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}; 
what in this case

Comment: @user16728494 in this case you will get some warnings. Use the the propper syntax. Do not be lazy. Some more `{}` will not hurt you https://godbolt.org/z/rPqbd9cbK